# From http response header Identifying does browser supports gzip or not

Tags: http, http-headers

Is it possible to identify "Does browser/client support gzip or not " ? using http header or request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If no Accept-Encoding field is present in a request, the server MAY assume that the client will accept any content coding." ([HTTPbis Part3](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p3-payload-16.html#header.accept-encoding))

Answer (score 0):

Browsers send this header if they accept gzip:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```